# How to not repeat same recent post in page twice?

Tags: php, wordpress

```
function getPostsbyCategoryID($category_id) {     
    $category_posts = wp_get_recent_posts(array('numberposts' => '3','category' => $category_id, 'post_status' => 'publish'), ARRAY_A );  
    $i = 0;   
    foreach($category_posts as $p) {    
        $i++;         
        echo '<li>';    
        echo '</li>';    
    }     
    wp_reset_query(); 
}
```

this is my query for getting posts from category and,
 i am using 
 for displaying post.
 I want to remove repeated recent posts, check the code if any error reply me, thanks

Comment: You mean other than you only output an empty `<li></li>` Do they count as duplicates?

Comment: Yes they are again repeating recent posts from starting i need it should exclude those post and display other posts

Answer (score 0):

I am no WP expert, but I can [read a manual](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_recent_posts)

There is an offset parameter that you can pass in this call, which should make it skip the first (x) posts

```
function getPostsbyCategoryID($category_id) {  

    $args = array('numberposts' => 3,
                  'offset' => 3,                    // <-- new line
                  'category' => $category_id, 
                  'post_status' => 'publish')    
    $category_posts = wp_get_recent_posts($args, , ARRAY_A );

    $i = 0;   
    foreach($category_posts as $p) {    
        $i++;         
        echo '<li>';    
        echo '</li>';    
    }     
    wp_reset_query(); 
}
```

Comment: i know that but offset i dont want to use offset because it wont display first 3 posts but i need it in different categories

Comment: Then I dont understand your question. Maybe if you give an example of what you are trying to achieve I can have another try at answering